# iterrows() and columns to identify entry locations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that is an attendance sheet.  Each row has a name followed by 53 columns representing weeks in a year.  When a person attends, that week gets a 1, otherwise it remains null.  I summed up each persons total attendance and made a histogram of visit counts.  There are a large number of people who attend less than 6 times in a year.  I want to look at the time span between visits; how many weeks between the first and last visit for each person who visited at least 2 times.   Below is an image of the `df.tail()`.  Index 1433 provides an example where the person visited 2 times, once in week 1 and again in week 46 which is 45 week span.    I tried  `for i,j in df.iterrows():` but I couldn't get it working and a am not sure it's a good idea.

[image]

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty simple and easy enough to understand.

setup:

```
cols = [f'WK_{i}' for i in range(1,54)]
data = {cols[i]:np.random.randint(0,2,10) for i in range(len(cols))}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   WK_1  WK_2  WK_3  WK_4  WK_5  WK_6  ...  WK_48  WK_49  WK_50  WK_51  WK_52  WK_53
0     1     1     0     0     0     0  ...      1      0      0      1      1      0
1     1     1     1     1     0     1  ...      1      0      0      1      0      0
2     1     0     0     1     1     1  ...      0      1      0      1      1      0
3     0     0     0     1     1     0  ...      1      1      0      0      1      1
4     1     1     1     1     0     1  ...      0      1      0      1      1      1
5     1     1     0     0     0     1  ...      0      0      1      0      0      1
6     0     1     1     0     1     0  ...      0      0      1      0      0      1
7     0     1     1     0     1     1  ...      0      0      1      1      1      0
8     0     0     1     1     0     0  ...      1      1      0      0      0      0
9     1     1     1     0     0     0  ...      0      1      1      0      0      1

[10 rows x 53 columns]
```

Transpose the df for easier series operations:

```
trans = df.T.reset_index()
>>> trans.head()
  index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  WK_1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1
1  WK_2  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  1
2  WK_3  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1
3  WK_4  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
4  WK_5  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0
```

Create a series of all attendances:

```
df.weeks_attended = df.apply(lambda x: trans.loc[trans[x.name]==1].index.tolist(),axis=1)
```

Finally, subtract first attendance from last attendance to get span:

```
df['span between visits'] = df.weeks_attended.apply(lambda x: x[-1]-x[0])
```

**Result:**

```
>>> df
   WK_1  WK_2  WK_3  WK_4  ...  WK_51  WK_52  WK_53  span between visits
0     1     0     0     1  ...      0      0      1                   52
1     1     0     0     1  ...      1      1      0                   51
2     1     0     0     0  ...      0      0      0                   45
3     1     0     0     1  ...      0      1      1                   52
4     0     0     1     0  ...      0      1      1                   50
5     1     0     1     1  ...      0      1      1                   52
6     0     1     0     1  ...      0      1      0                   50
7     0     0     0     1  ...      0      0      0                   42
8     1     0     1     1  ...      1      1      1                   52
9     0     0     1     1  ...      1      0      1                   50
```

Comment: shouldn't the span between visits be lesser. For example, on row 2, wk_51 and wk_52 had a visit. However, wk_1 and wk_4 had visit but there were no visits for wk_2 and wk_3. Wouldn't the span between visits be 3 weeks?

Comment: Here I think the span between visits is actually the 'total span' between the **first** and **final** visit.   That is what I was asking for, though I am curious about average span between each consecutive visit as well--eventually.   I will try this Transpose method as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @Boskosnitch Thank you.  Your technique is very fast generating the lists of "weeks_attended," but I'm running into a glitch getting the final "span."  I used your suggestion for span,``` df['span between visits'] = df.weeks_attended.apply(lambda x: x[-1]-x[0])``` on the technique @Joe Ferndz suggested for creating the list of weeks_attended and it works well.   However, this same span calc/script is giving a "list index out of range" error when I try it on your method incorporating transposed df.  I'm baffled why.  Also, where does "x.name" come from?  I need to read about the name method..

Comment: @Glenn The x.name operator returns the index of the row when doing a row-wise apply operation (axis=1). I would guess that maybe an index error might be caused by a row in which only one attendance was recorded, which did not occur in the example df I created for testing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining x.name, Boskosnitch.  You are right, I dropped the single visits, and 'span' now calculates fine.  Curious why it worked with the other method, without dropping the single visits.  In those cases, the span calculated as 0.     Thank you for your help with this problem, and for the instruction in general.  Since this method is significantly faster, I will check it off.  Both methods work, so thank you as well to @Joe Ferndz as your method is also instructive.  I will keep in my notebook as I look closer into this "food bank" stats project.

Answer (score 2):

## Using [first_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) & [last_valid_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html)

Pandas has the first_valid_index and last_valid_index to get you the index of not_null position. You can find the positions by slicing the dataframe to the 52 weeks using iloc. In the below example, I am slicing it for 15 weeks only (0 thru 14). To get the index as an integer, create a dictionary with column names and position. Use that to subtract the difference and get the gap.

Here's the code to do this.

```
dcols = {'wk'+str(i+1):i+1 for i in range (53)}

df['start_pos'] = df.iloc[:,0:15].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1).replace(dcols)

df['end_pos'] = df.iloc[:,0:15].apply(lambda x: x.last_valid_index(), axis=1).replace(dcols)

df['visit_gap'] = df['end_pos'] - df['start_pos']
print (df[['start_pos','end_pos','visit_gap']])
```

If you want to check this for only rows where visit is 2 or more, just add it to the condition.

The output from my previous shared data (see below for data) is:

```
   start_pos  end_pos  visit_gap
0          2       15         13
1          1       15         14
2          4       10          6
```

## Using Apply and list

Here is a way to address it. You can use apply function on the dataframe and iterate through each column for a given row to find out if it is a notnull. If it is, capture the column #. This will give you all the columns that have notnull. Once you have that, it is simpler to find the maximum difference between two column indexes. That will give you the maximum gap between two visits.

Code to do this is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.DataFrame({'wk1': [np.nan,1,np.nan],       'wk2': [1,np.nan,np.nan], 
                   'wk3': [1,1,np.nan],            'wk4': [np.nan,np.nan,1], 
                   'wk5': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],  'wk6': [1,1,np.nan],
                   'wk7': [1,1,np.nan],            'wk8': [1,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'wk9': [np.nan,1,np.nan],       'wk10': [np.nan,np.nan,1],
                   'wk11': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'wk12': [1,1,np.nan],
                   'wk13': [np.nan,1,np.nan],      'wk14': [1,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'wk15': [1,1,np.nan],           'wk16': [np.nan,1,np.nan], 
                   'wk17': [1,np.nan,np.nan],      'wk18': [1,1,np.nan],
                   'wk19': [np.nan,1,np.nan],      'wk20': [1,np.nan,1],
                   'wk21': [1,1,np.nan], })

#print (df)
df['attendance'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i,c in enumerate(df.columns) if pd.notnull(x[c])], axis=1)
print (df)
```

Here's the output:

```
   wk1  wk2  wk3  wk4  wk5  wk6  wk7  wk8  wk9  wk10  wk11  wk12  wk13  wk14  \
0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   1.0   
1  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN   
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

   wk15  wk16  wk17  wk18  wk19  wk20  wk21  \
0   1.0   NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN   1.0   1.0   
1   1.0   1.0   NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN   1.0   
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   

                                    attendance  
0  [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20]  
1  [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20]  
2                                   [3, 9, 19]
```

The last column now has values that you can iterate thru and find out how frequently they attended.

If you want number of visits, you can simply do:

```
df["Total_Visits"] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Since your last column is `'Total_Visits'`, your apply statement has to use `df.columns[:-1]`

If you want to get the maximum gap between two visits, then you can give this.

```
df['max_gap'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(np.diff([i for i,c in enumerate(df.columns) if pd.notnull(x[c])])), axis=1)
```

Output of this will be:

```
   max_gap                                   attendance
0        4  [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20]
1        3  [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20]
2       10                                   [3, 9, 19]
```

To find maximum gap, you need to consider 'Total_Visits' column as well. That way you can find out if someone in week 10 and never visited after. The maximum gap would be from 52 week - 10 week. To get this, we need to include 'Total_Visits'. That's why we will iterate through `df.columns` and not `df.columns[:-1]`

Comment: Thank you.  I believe this is exactly what I need, but I have been struggling with it.  The [attendance] and Total_Visits aren't matching.  I don't know if this could be due to the 1s being entered in excel, and the df is imported.  Though I'd assume if a 1 had a space (and was treated as a str), both counts would be equally off.

Comment: @ Joe Ferndz, I was summing total visits, in the same way, prior to your suggestion.  I never checked the accuracy as it looked correct, but after running the 'attendance' script, I realized there was an issue with the sum.  I found I need to run ```df["Total_Visits"] = df.notnull().sum(axis=1)```   apparently the NaN values cause errors,  I will now continue to follow your advice to and try someing like,  attendance[-1] - attendance[0].  I also appreciate the max gap calc too.

Comment: if your column value has strings `'1'`, then it will NOT count. you may have to convert it and then sum. Try this `df.astype(float).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: You can also do a `len(attendance)` to get the # of days the person visited/attended.